# How do I move my code containing a foreach loop inside echo do_shortcode?

Tags: php, woocommerce, foreach, echo, shortcode

I have this working code that I need to move to be inside of `echo do_shortcode`:

```
/**
 * @var WP_user $user
 */

// in this file $user is defined - see last snippet
use OneSignalNotificator\Frontend\WooCommerce\WooCommerceAccountNotificationsPanel;


foreach (WooCommerceAccountNotificationsPanel::fields as $fieldName => $fieldSettings) {
    woocommerce_form_field( $fieldName, 
                            $fieldSettings, 
                            get_user_meta($user->ID,    
                            $fieldName, 
                            true) ?? null
    );
}
```

As I am using trial and error so far, I start with the shortcode ready for PHP to be added inside of it:
`echo do_shortcode('[wcm_restrict]' . ' [/wcm_restrict]');`

First I try copy and pasting the code into the shortcode, and I'm sure I don't have to tell you that does not work.

Next, I tried using buffer but it did not seem to execute the shortcode, and that the code inside the buffer was still executed:

```
ob_start(); // start buffer
foreach (WooCommerceAccountNotificationsPanel::fields as $fieldName => $fieldSettings) {
    woocommerce_form_field(
                            $fieldName,
                            $fieldSettings,
                            get_user_meta($user->ID, $fieldName, true) ?? null
    );
}
    $output = ob_get_clean(); // set the buffer data to variable and clean the buffer

    echo do_shortcode('[wcm_restrict]' . $output . ' [/wcm_restrict]');
```

Then i tried using wrapping the code with a function, and executing it in the shortcode:

```
function moveCode(){
    foreach (WooCommerceAccountNotificationsPanel::fields as $fieldName => $fieldSettings) {
        woocommerce_form_field(
                $fieldName,
                $fieldSettings,
                get_user_meta($user->ID, $fieldName, true) ?? null
            );
    }
}

echo do_shortcode('[wcm_restrict]' . moveCode() . ' [/wcm_restrict]');
```

And *that* throws an error for $user:

"Undefined variable '$user'"

[image]

I've tried similar questions here and on the net and haven't got it right. What do I need to do to execute the code inside the shortcode?

EDIT / UPDATE:

`$user` is defined in another file (which I've added to the top of the first snippet):

```
add_action('woocommerce_account_notifications-settings_endpoint', function () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    // removed extra code for readability

    require_once('templates/notification-settings.php');
});
```

Comment: Thank you @RiggsFolly for editing the whitespace I left! I'll be sure to do that in the future.

Comment: where is `$user` defined?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain that, but it's in a file via `use ` as `$user = wp_get_current_user();`